# C# - How to retrieve lists by their description?

Tags: list, csom, caml-query

How does one retrieve specific lists based on a "WHERE" query on the list's description?

Basically, I've used the description as my query since there are too many default lists in SharePoint site. I wanted to ignore lists that do not meet my "special description". [This C# code tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538683(v=office.14).aspx) retrieves everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use LINQ to filter out those lists or using LoadQuery.

You can try using the below two options

**Option 1** - Better option and will be a bit lighter

```
using(ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{

    var specialLists = clientContext.LoadQuery(clientContext.Web.Lists.Where(l => l.Description == "Special Description"));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach(var list in specialLists)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Modified from - [Load vs LoadQuery in SP 2013](http://sharepointdarwish.blogspot.in/2015/03/load-vs-loadquery-sharepoint-2013-csom.html)

**Option 2** - Will be a bit heavier since it uses LINQ and filters after all the lists are loaded

```
using(ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
    ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;

    clientContext.Load(collList);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var mySpecialLists = collList.Where(l => l.Description == "Special description");

    foreach(var list in mySpecialLists)
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently, this is what I'm doing to speed-up iterations. However, I'm trying to avoid this (loading all Lists in memory) as it is filling up RAM due to too many sites I would like to ignore. Thank you.

Comment: You can't query by description without fetching them all. This is the best answer you're going to get.

Comment: You can create a CAML query that will process server side and just return the matching results.

Comment: For option 1, I get this error: 'The data is not available. The query may not have been executed.' Do you think it has something to do with my server being SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Hmm, looks like the issue could be because you are using SP 2010. Works perfectly fine in 2013 and Online

Comment: The error was mine. I apologize. Option 1 is the taken answer. Thank you!